# Access SQL. Detecting an alphabetical character in a string

Tags: ms-access, while-loop, vba, sql-update, ms-access-2007

I am trying to update a field named `New_ParcelNum` to `FLAG` depending on if an alphabetical character is located in the string.

```
'FLAG anything with a letter.
sql_UpdateNew = "DECLARE @Counter INT;" & _
                "SET @Counter = ASCII('A');" & _
                "WHILE Counter <= ASCII('Z') " & _
                "BEGIN" & _
                "IIF(INSTR(tblParcelNumber, CHAR(@Counter)) > 0, " & _
                    "UPDATE tblParcelNumber SET tblParcelNumber.New_ParcelNum = 'FLAG', " & _
                    "tblParcelNumber.New_ParcelNum);" & _
                "SET @Counter = @ Counter + 1;" & _
                "END;"
DoCmd.RunSQL sql_UpdateNew
```

I keep getting a run-time error:

> (3129), invalid SQL statement. Expected DELETE, INSERT, PROCEDURE, SELECT, UPDATE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you the problem: you can't use RunSql for complex procedural code (in fact, I don't hink you can do that stuff in Access SQL *at all*--those are using specific T-SQL extensions).

The "SQL Statement" portion is described thus:

> A string expression that's a valid SQL statement for an action query or a data-definition query. It uses an INSERT INTO, DELETE, SELECT...INTO, UPDATE, CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE, DROP TABLE, CREATE INDEX, or DROP INDEX statement. Include an IN clause if you want to access another database.

See full description [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194626.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

How about basing your SQL Server update with a where clause similar to: 
WHERE IsNumeric(tblParcelNumber) = 1 <<>>